# Python Seaborn - How are outliers determined in boxplots

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to know what algorithm is used to determine the 'outliers' in a boxplot distribution in Seaborn.

On their website [seaborn.boxplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) they simple state:

> The box shows the quartiles of the dataset while the whiskers extend
>   to show the rest of the distribution, except for points that are
>   determined to be “outliers” using a method that is a function of the
>   inter-quartile range.

I would really like to know what method they use. I've created boxplots from a dataframe and I seem to have a lot of 'outliers'.

[image: boxplots of my dataframe]
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read further on the page you linked (or ctrl-f for "outlier"), you will see:

```
whis : float, optional
    Proportion of the IQR past the low and high quartiles to extend the plot whiskers.
    Points outside this range will be identified as outliers.
```

Comment: Does that not mean that every distribution will have outliers? Not all of mine do

Comment: No. Why do you think it would?

Comment: The rule is what Tukey defined, as explicated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot).

Comment: For a normal distribution the standard whiskers range of 1.5xIQR cover 99.3% of the distribution (see Fig 5 in the wikipedia link by @mwaskon). But of course, if you have enough data, you will eventually get outliers. Is that what you had in mind, @jut199?

Answer (score 11):

It appears, by testing, that seaborn uses `whis=1.5` as the default.

`whis` is defined as the

> Proportion of the IQR past the low and high quartiles to extend the plot
>   whiskers.

For a normal distribution, the [interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) contains 50% of the population and 1.5 * IQR contains about 99%.

Answer (score 8):

You can calculate it this way:

```
Q1 = df.quartile(0.25)
Q3 = df.quartile(0.75)
    
IQR = Q3 - Q1
```

It's an outlier if it is less than:

```
Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
```

or if it is greater than:

```
Q3 + 1.5 * IQR
```